# Node.jsのhttp.Server.on()メソッドについて

Tags: node.js

Node.jsを勉強中です。

簡易的なWebサーバを書いてみようと下記リファレンスやブログ記事などを参考にしています。
https://nodejs.org/api/index.html

リファレンス内のサンプルコードや個人ブログなどで、以下のような書き方があります。

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();

server.on(　～～
```

この`server.on`というメソッドがリファレンスのHTTPのページから見つけ出せず、
どんな仕様なのかわからない状態です。

どなたかご存知でしたらご回答いただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`http.Server`を含む多くのNode.jsの組み込みクラスは[EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)を継承しており、この`.on`もその一部です。

[emitter.on(eventName, listener)](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener)

各イベントについては各クラスのドキュメントにあるとおりです。`emitter.on`はサンプルでも使われている通り、イベント名とリスナーのコールバックを引数にとります。
コールバックの引数も各クラスのドキュメントにあるとおりで、例えば`http.Server`の[Event: 'request'](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request)であれば`(request: http.IncomingMessage, response: http.ServerResponse)` が引数として渡されます。

---

そういえばNode.jsのクラス図作られてる方も居たので参考に:
[Node.jsクラス図(v10.0.0対応版) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/darai0512/items/7abc5393372f63be1e2e)

Comment: なるほど、EventEmitterも継承しているんですね。納得がいきました！非常に助かりました！ご回答、ありがとうございました。